# live video streaming from php and or flash?

Tags: php, flash, html, html5-video, live-streaming

I need to make a live streaming webcam application from my php server to a php page. I could either take frame by frame pictures using flash and somehow convert them to video files and stream it through or bundle the images together, compress them, and  outputting it on a web page. any help with php methods to convert images to videos and outputting them on a web page?

Comment: You need to encode your video as video at the source.  Capturing video is completely different than capturing single frames.  Also note that this really doesn't have anything to do with PHP.  It would be quite the task to record video from a camera with PHP and stream it.  Use a tool such as the free Flash Media Encoder for this.

Comment: can you please link it? iphone att&t internet is really bad. So if i get it right, i would capture it using flash, then create a loop that constantly takes pictures converts it into videos and output it on a webpage as video? i need to do this iphone is not flash friendly. thanks

Comment: i am also doing this. i am having a hard time outputting it as a video without flash. =/

Comment: Your question says you want to use Flash.  If you don't want to use Flash, you should change your question.  No, capturing videos is *not* the same as taking pictures and converting to video.  As I said, if you want to capture video, you need to capture video.  You then need a server for streaming this video.

Comment: how would i go about capturing video files and streaming them on a php server?

Answer (score 2):

> I could either take frame by frame pictures using flash

I did this once. Result? An awful, CPU hogging mess. It worked, no doubt about that. But it was terrible. Because the images had to be encoded every 500ms (half a second), my CPU (Intel i7 4 cores) went up to **70%** in usage. So I suggest you stay away from that method unless of course, you want your users to kill you?

I would suggest taking a look at the Flash Media Server. It's not free but there is a free trial for you to try. Here, take a look at [this](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashmediaserver/articles/beginner_installing_fm3.html).